# Statement oApp.Namespace(CVar(tempfolder)).CopyHere oApp.Namespace(CVar(ZipFile)).Items is taking longer time to finish

Tags: excel, vba, antivirus, windows-defender

I have come across an issue recently in my vba macro code
below line:

```
oApp.Namespace(CVar(tempExtractFolder)).CopyHere
oApp.Namespace(CVar(ZipFile)).Items
```

It is taking a longer time to complete copying items inside the Zipfile (here the Zipfile is the .xlsm file changed it's extension to .zip) when windows defender is turned on with real time scan. The size of the xlsm file before changing its extension is just less than 1 MB.

When we turn off the windows defender real time scan, everything is working normally, no performance issue observed.

We used `oApp.Namespace(CVar(tempExtractFolder)).CopyHere` in the past and it worked fine, we did not made any changes to it, the issue just started coming recently. Not sure if it is an issue with windows defender recent update if any in case.

When windows defender is turned off then no performance issue is observed, I'm expecting `CopyHere` to work in same way when windows defender turned on or off.

Comment: You could try running the code from a [Trusted Location](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-remove-or-change-a-trusted-location-in-microsoft-office-7ee1cdc2-483e-4cbb-bcb3-4e7c67147fb4) ... if your code is in a macro-enabled Excel workbook then that means to move it into an already Trusted Location (ie a folder) or to Trust the Location it is already in